# "她从他的邻居那里借了一把铁锹，现在他正在用这把铁锹挖泥土。" What does "那里" contribute to this sentence's meaning?

Tags: translation, grammar, ambiguity

"她从他的邻居那里借了一把铁锹，现在他正在用这把铁锹挖泥土。" In the first half of this sentence, the speaker uses "那里." I'd love to know how it affects the meaning of the sentence. For example, if we remove 那里, what happens to the meaning of the sentence?

Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "她[**从**]他的[**邻居那里**]借了一把铁锹，现在他正在用这把铁锹挖泥土。

[**从**] = **from**

[邻居**那里**]= Neighbor's **place**

If you just write 邻居 without 那里, the sentence would become "她[**向**]他的[**邻居**]借了一把铁锹

- 从(from)--> 邻居那里(somewhere) --> 借(borrow) = borrow from a neighbor's place
- 向(go to)--> 邻居(someone) --> 借(to borrow) = borrow from a neighbor

Similar example:

向[银行 (*who*)]借钱

从[银行那里(*where*)]借钱

Comment: Once again, a beautiful lesson! Thanks, so much!!